# Biased CNN model

Tags: testing, conv-neural-network, training-data, generalization

I am training a CNN model to classify binary data. It seem to be strongly biased towards one class when an unseen data pattern (Data pattern which it has never seen before during training) is passed. It would make sense if it gives a neutral value(between two classes) for unseen data patterns but it seem to be biased towards one class. Any ideas on why this happens?

My current model is below,

```css
def build_model(max_features, maxlen):

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(max_features, 4, input_length=maxlen))
    model.add(Convolution1D(64, 2, border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Convolution1D(32, 3, border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Convolution1D(16, 4, border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    #model.add(Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'))
    #model.add(Dense(180,activation='sigmoid'))
    #model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the training data or the labeling? Do you have enough samples for the second class?

Comment: Yes I have well balanced training dataset